# Enteprise wiki site didn't show welcom list

Tags: wiki, enterprise-wiki

Is it possible to display welcome promoted links in wiki site as displayed in the team site home page

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, it's a `Get Started with your site web part` that can be added easily as the following:

- Just edit your page > From the above ribbon > Click on insert tab > click on web part.
- At `Media and Content` section, > Click on `Get Started with your site`.

[image]

**[OutPut]**

[image]